# SSRS report not working in Sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint

We have SSRS service application configured over SharePoint site and through RDL files and stored procedure we are fetching the SSRS report.

There was MS patching occurred over the environment after which old RDL files are working but while uploading new RDL files through visual studio to SharePoint list, we are getting below error :

> Server was unable to process request. ---> An error occurred while receiving the HTTP response to http://ndc3cwnpcosmos6:32843/f5dd0dbf5c2a4b569a972d4017fdc784/ReportingWebService.svc. This could be due to the service endpoint binding not using the HTTP protocol. This could also be due to an HTTP request context being aborted by the server (possibly due to the service shutting down). See server logs for more details. ---> An error occurred while receiving the HTTP response to http://ndc3cwnpcosmos6:32843/f5dd0dbf5c2a4b569a972d4017fdc784/ReportingWebService.svc. This could be due to the service endpoint binding not using the HTTP protocol. This could also be due to an HTTP request context being aborted by the server (possibly due to the service shutting down). See server logs for more details. ---> The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive. ---> Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. ---> An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Anyone please help